# Can we say that a "relative frequency distribution" is a representation of a "probability mass function"?

Tags: probability, distributions

Since:

1. the "probability mass function" gives the probability that a discrete random variable is exactly equal to some value, and, therefore, we can think about it as a hypothetical outcome that might occur (or not) in the future,
2. the "relative frequency distribution" is built upon an observed, and therefore already past, event,

Can we state that a "relative frequency distribution" is one of the possible "representations" of a "Probability Mass Function"?

Comment: By "relative frequency distribution" are you referring to an [eCDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function)?

Comment: I refer to "Relative frequency distribution: a frequency distribution where each value has been divided (normalized) by a number of outcomes in a sample (i.e. sample size)." from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution

Comment: Oh yes, so the first difference of the eCDF would be the relative frequency distribution. In a sense the relative frequency distribution **is** the sample probability mass function. This sample probability mass distribution is often going to be considered an estimate of a population probability mass distribution.

Comment: @Galen It's not the first difference except in exceptional cases where the data are supported on an interval of integers.  Relative frequencies *are,* by definition, the probability function corresponding to the ECDF.

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, you used some terminology I am not familiar with, i.e. 
(i) "sample probability mass function" (instead of simply using "probability mass function"), (ii) "sample probability mass distribution" and (iii) "population probability mass distribution".  Could you define them? In addition, could you please explain better what you meant with: (i) "first difference of the eCDF would be the frequency distribution".

Comment: @whuber Oops, thank you for the correction. Indeed, an interval of integers for the support was what had come to mind.

Comment: @limone 

$$\text{sample probability mass function} \equiv \text{sample probability mass distribution}$$

and likewise population probability mass distribution is just a rephrasing of a population [PMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function). 

Formally there is a difference between [functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) and [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)), but I am not making anything of it here.

Comment: ah ok, now it is clearer, thanks!